# What is the easier way to convert single string word without spaces into Title case within less code?

Tags: javascript, string

I have single string and I want to convert this to title case.
JS is not providing built in function.

```js
var difficulty = "easy";  // medium, hard
    difficulty[0].toUpperCase();
    document.write(difficulty)  // It is printing in small.
```

Comment: `.toUpperCase()` doesn't modify, it returns a new string - you have to assign it.

Comment: Should I assign a first variable to a variable with uppercase then re assign to first index ?

Comment: strings are immutable so you can't reassign index

Comment: Yes it is not reassigning a string character to updated character.

Comment: simply use css `text-transform: capitalize;`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to repeat the code multiple times, you can add a method to the String prototype, that would allow you to easily reuse the functionality many times

```js
String.prototype.titleCase = function () {
 var sentence = this.toLowerCase().split(" ");
 for(var i = 0; i< sentence.length; i++){
    sentence[i] = sentence[i][0].toUpperCase() + sentence[i].slice(1);
 }
return sentence.join(" ");
}
 
var difficulty = "easy";

document.write(difficulty.titleCase());
document.write("<br/>")
document.write("medium".titleCase());
document.write("<br/>")
document.write("hard".titleCase());
```

This will also work on words with spaces, so `very easy // would give "Very Easy"`

Comment: Is there any short way to do this like @Kyoko Sasagava answer ?